# PowerShell sqlite3 memory issues

Tags: powershell, sqlite

I am writing a ps script that will convert the records of a .db file into a .csv file.  The .db file is over 14,000,000 kb.  I decided to loop through the records in an effort to avoid the memory issue however, I still get the our of memory error.  Is there any way to 'clear' the memory between inserts to keep the RAM down?

```
   $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EXPORT;
            CREATE TABLE EXPORT AS SELECT sha256, sha1, md5, crc32, file_name, file_size, package_id FROM FILE;
            UPDATE EXPORT SET file_name = REPLACE(file_name, '`"', '');
            "
    $sql | sqlite3 $DBfile2Convert
    $sqla = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EXPORT;"
    $obja = $sqla | sqlite3 $DBfile2Convert
    $TotalItems = $obja
    $CurrentItem = 0
    $PercentComplete = 0
    Write-Host ""
    1..$obja | % {
        $sqla = "SELECT '`"' || sha256 || '`"', '`"' || sha1 || '`"', '`"' || md5 || '`"', '`"' || crc32 || '`"', '`"' || file_name || '`"', file_size, package_id, '`"' || 0 || '`"', '`"' || '`"' FROM EXPORT ORDER BY sha1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + $_ + ";"
        $sqla | sqlite3 $DBfile2Convert | Add-Content -Path output.txt
        Write-Progress -Activity "Exporting DB Rows to CSV" -Status "$PercentComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -lt "5")  {$PERC = "[                    ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "5")  {$PERC = "[0                   ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "10") {$PERC = "[00                  ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "15") {$PERC = "[000                 ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "20") {$PERC = "[0000                ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "25") {$PERC = "[00000               ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "30") {$PERC = "[000000              ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "35") {$PERC = "[0000000             ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "40") {$PERC = "[00000000            ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "45") {$PERC = "[000000000           ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "50") {$PERC = "[0000000000          ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "55") {$PERC = "[00000000000         ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "60") {$PERC = "[000000000000        ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "65") {$PERC = "[0000000000000       ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "70") {$PERC = "[00000000000000      ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "75") {$PERC = "[000000000000000     ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "80") {$PERC = "[0000000000000000    ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "85") {$PERC = "[00000000000000000   ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "90") {$PERC = "[000000000000000000  ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "95") {$PERC = "[0000000000000000000 ]"}
        If ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100) -eq "100"){$PERC = "[00000000000000000000]"}
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "`r  $PercentComplete% COMPLETE     $PERC"
        $PercentComplete = ([int](($_ / $obja) * 100))
    }
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Progress -Activity "Exporting DB Rows to CSV" -Status "Done" -Completed
    Set-Content "${DBfile2Convert}.csv" '"SHA-256","SHA-1","MD5","CRC32","FileName","FileSize","ProductCode","OpSystemCode","SpecialCode"'
    Get-Content output.txt | Foreach-Object {$_.Replace('"""', '"')} | Foreach-Object {$_.Replace('|', ',')} | Add-Content "${DBfile2Convert}.csv"
    Remove-Item "output.txt" -Force
```

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cli.html#export_to_csv

Comment: @codymatthew @shawn’s comment is the probably way to go, but note that your existing code will spend about 90% of its time updating the progress bar - ```write-progress``` and ```write-host``` are relatively slow, so you’d be better off only calling them every, say, 100 or 1000 (or more) iterations anyway…